# oracle decode not working well with character

Tags: oracle

I have table with a field (flag) that has either 'T' or 'F' values, when I execute the following statement it shows records:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DECODE(flag,'F',0,'T',1,NULL) is null AND flag='F';
```

while it is supposed to not. The decode function always do that with this specific table. My first thought was encoding problem but the above statement cancel this thought.
I'll be thankful if anyone helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that the datatype of `flag` is a CHAR and not a VARCHAR2?
That would be consistent with the behaviour shown below...

```
create table t1(
  flag  char(2)
 ,flag2 varchar2(2) 
);

insert into t1 values('F', 'F');
insert into t1 values('T', 'T');
insert into t1 values('X', 'X');
insert into t1 values(null, null);

commit;


select decode(flag,  'F', 0, 'T', 1, null) as with_char
      ,decode(flag2, 'F', 0, 'T', 1, null) as with_varchar
  from t1;

WITH_CHAR   WITH_VARCHAR
----------  ------------
   null          0
   null          1
   null         null
   null         null
```

To fix this, you'd either have to:

1. Rewrite your logic (**preferrable**)
2. Use `DECODE(TRIM(flag), ...)`
3. Change data type to VARCHAR2

### Edit: Why is flag = 'F' true?

This is because the expression `'F'` has an implicit data type of `CHAR(1)`. In the special case of comparing two `char(x)` expressions, Oracle would blankpad the shorter of them to the length of the longer column. Apparently, this is a requirement of the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

The flag column will already be blankpadded to `'F '` according to char(2) semantics and when oracle sees your `'F'` expression, it realizes that is compares char(2) to char(1) and blankpads your `'F'` expression to `'F '`.

And that is why `'F' = 'F '` :)

Not so with `DECODE` though, because here `'F' <> 'F '`. This is not the only time when DECODE is inconsistent with SQL and you should try to avoid it.

You can read more in the [CHAR versus VARCHAR2 Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm) chapter in Oracle documentation.

Comment: Thank you , I noticed that the flag type is char(2), the trim solves the problem

Comment: But why flag='F' is true?